# how to insert values into database table that is added to a different column depending on selection in combobox

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, drop-down-menu, combobox

Good day, I hope you support me with this query, ** how can I insert the value of a select-option (combobox) php in multiple columns in a table in mysql depending on the selected data? **

For example I have a submit form linked to a nested combobox, the last select-option contains 3 values: `peras(pears), manzanas(apples), naranjas(oranges)`.I would like that if i select value "pears" this value is inserted into column id_peras, and if i select oranges this value is inserted in column id_naranjas.
this is my code until now:

this is my mysql database table named "frutas"

```
id |id_ciudad |id_colonia |id_participante |id_fruta
```

i would like that it table looks like this one:

```
id |id_ciudad |id_colonia |id_participante |id_peras |id_manzanas |id_naranjas
```

---

**index.php**

```
<div class="container">

<h1>
Seleccionar Participante
</h1>

<form id="frm-Participante" action="procesar.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="id_jugador"  />

<?php
//Include database configuration file

//Get all country data
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ciudades ORDER BY nombre_ciudad ASC");

//Count total number of rows
$rowCount = $query->num_rows;
?>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Ciudad</label>
<select name="id_ciudad" id="Ciudad" class="form-control" >
    <option value="">Seleccione la Ciudad</option>
    <?php
    if($rowCount > 0){
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
            echo '<option value="'.$row['id_ciudad'].'">'.$row['nombre_ciudad'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">no hay ciudades</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Colonia</label>
<select name="id_colonia" id="Colonia" class="form-control" disabled="disabled">
    <option value="">Seleccione la Colonia</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Participante</label>
<select name="id_participante" id="Participante" class="form-control" disabled="disabled">
    <option value="">Seleccione el Participante</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Eleccion del Participante</label>
    <select name="id_fruta" id="Fruta" class="form-control" disabled="disabled">
        <option  value="1">Peras</option>
        <option  value="2">Manzanas</option>
        <option  value="3">Naranjas</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="upload-result text-center">
    <button class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button>
</div>

</form>
</div>



</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#frm-Participante").submit(function(){
        return $(this).validate();
    });
});

    </script>
<script>


$('#Ciudad').change(function(){
$('#Colonia').removeAttr('disabled');
});

$('#Colonia').change(function(){
$('#Participante').removeAttr('disabled');
});

$('#Participante').change(function(){
$('#Fruta').removeAttr('disabled');
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#frm-Participante").submit(function(){
        return $(this).validate();
    });
});

    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#Ciudad').on('change',function(){
    var CiudadID = $(this).val();
    if(CiudadID){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'ajaxData.php',
            data:'id_categoria='+CiudadID,
            success:function(html){
                $('#Colonia').html(html);
                $('#Participante').html('<option value="">Seleccione el Colonia primero</option>')
                $('#Participante').attr('disabled','disabled');
                $('#Fruta').attr('disabled','disabled');
            }
        }); 
    }else{
        $('#Colonia').html('<option value="">Seleccione Ciudad primero</option>');
        $('#Participante').html('<option value="">Seleccione Colonia primero</option>');
        $('#Colonia').attr('disabled','disabled');
        $('#Participante').attr('disabled','disabled');
        $('#Fruta').attr('disabled','disabled');

    }
});

$('#Colonia').on('change',function(){
    var ColoniaID = $(this).val();
    if(ColoniaID){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'ajaxData.php',
            data:'id_colonia='+ColoniaID,
            success:function(html){
                $('#Participante').html(html);
            }
        }); 
    }else{
        $('#Colonia').html('<option value="">Seleccione Colonia primero</option>');
        $('#Participante').attr('disabled','disabled');
        $('#Fruta').attr('disabled','disabled'); 
    }
});
});
</script>
```

---

**procesar.php**

```
<?php    
require_once'conexion.php';
include'funciones.php';

bd_agregar($_REQUEST);

//Cerramos conexión.
$cone->close();     
?>

</body>

</html>
```

---

**funciones.php**

```
<?php
require_once'conexion.php';

//Creamos función
function bd_agregar($temp){
//Especificamos variable global.
global $cone;

//Obtenemos datos formulario
$id_ciudad = $_REQUEST['id_ciudad'];
$id_colonia = $_REQUEST['id_colonia'];
$id_participante = $_REQUEST['id_participante'];
$id_fruta = $_REQUEST['id_fruta'];

//Insertamos datos
$cone->query("INSERT INTO frutas (id_ciudad,id_colonia,id_participante,id_fruta) VALUES ('$id_ciudad','$id_colonia','$id_participante','$id_fruta')");         
  echo $id_ciudad.$id_colonia.$id_jugador.$id_fruta;
}

//Comprobamos ejecución sentencia.
if ($cone===false) {
printf("Mensaje de error: %s\n", $cone->error);
} else {
echo "Los datos se insertaron correctamente";
}
?>
```

**sql**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `frutas` (
`id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_ciudad` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`id_colonia` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`id_participante` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`id_peras` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`id_manzanas` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`id_naranjas` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
COMMIT;
```

i tried with switch case but i haven´t success the data is not inserted into database

```
function bd_agregar($temp){
//Especificamos variable global.
global $cone;

//Obtenemos datos formulario
$id_ciudad = $_REQUEST['id_ciudad'];
$id_colonia = $_REQUEST['id_colonia'];
$id_participante = $_REQUEST['id_participante'];
$id_fruta = $_REQUEST['id_fruta'];

switch($id_fruta) {

case '1':
    // Creas una variable que guarde la consulta con el nombre de columna id_peras
    $sql = "INSERT INTO frutas (id_ciudad,id_colonia,id_participante,id_gol) VALUES ('$id_ciudad','$id_colonia','$id_participante','$id_fruta')";
    break;
case '2':
    // Creas una variable que guarde la consulta con el nombre de columna id_manzanas
    $sql = "INSERT INTO frutas (id_ciudad,id_colonia,id_participante,id_amarilla) VALUES ('$id_ciudad','$id_colonia','$id_participante','$id_fruta')";
    break;
case '3':
    // Creas una variable que guarde la consulta con el nombre de columna id_naranjas
    $sql = "INSERT INTO frutas (id_ciudad,id_colonia,id_participante,id_roja) VALUES ('$id_ciudad','$id_colonia','$id_participante','$id_fruta')";
    break;
default:
    echo "Valor erróneo"; die;

}

//Insertamos datos
// Pasamos la varriable $sql
  $cone->query($sql);         
  echo $id_ciudad.$id_colonia.$id_participante.$id_fruta;
}
```

thank you in advance

Comment: I feel like this is a question pertaining to database design / Normalization.  Rather than blow out a less-maintainable table structure which gives every option a column, perhaps build a lighter table structure that genrates an `id`, the `category`, and the submitted value.  That said, I lost interest in reading the entire question because it was so long and I couldn't read the non-English.

Comment: Hello, you should try to create a more concise question / example. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

first of all i would suggest you, that you change your database design. Instead of using 3 different columns for each case of your selectbox you could use an enum('1','2','3').
Then you can simply insert the value of the selected box into that column.
And later on for the frontend you just output for each value a different string. You can also add strings into your enum instead of numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, in this case I was thinking about this table structure because I need this data to be visible for each registered participant, and also to be able to add the values ​​of each participant, that is, if the participant john doe selected today an apple and tomorrow also select apple would be added 2 apples for john doe, if the third day you select a pear then it would be 2 apples and 1 pear for john doe. later that information is displayed in a datatable. participant_id | pears | apples | orange